XSLT 2 or 3 How to convert <!--/ COMMENT --> in to encapsulating element in output markup
I need to convert no compliant html into xml so I can process thousands of documents in the required json format with XSLT.
          <!-- IMAGECOUNT -->
      <table width="100%">
         <tr>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
               <strong>
2 Images
</strong>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <!-- /IMAGECOUNT -->
      <p>
         <strong>
<!-- SECTION -->
The section 
<!-- /SECTION -->
<!-- COUNTRY -->
The country
<!-- /COUNTRY -->


</strong>
      </p>
      <!-- DATE -->
      <p>
         <font size="-1">
            <b>Date Posted: 09-Dec-2019</b>
         </font>
      </p>
      <!-- /DATE -->
      <!-- TEXT -->
      <center>
         <p>
            <font size="-1">
Just some text
</font>
         </p>
      </center>
      <!-- /TEXT -->
      <!-- TOP THUMBNAILS -->
      <table class="tabletopbottom" width="100%">
         <tr>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
               <img src="images/s1353556.jpg" alt="Cat"/>
               <img src="images/s1164352.jpg" alt="Dog"/>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <!-- /TOP THUMBNAILS -->

I need to add structure to the HTML so that I can use a another XSLT to remove all the  elements that are not important final Json.
This seems like a group-with @starting-with problem but I can't get the logic to gobble up the following-siblings until the next matching end comment is found.
Start Comment
  <!-- IMAGECOUNT -->
    Lots of content that needs to be children of this new element
  <!-- /IMAGECOUNT -->

Here my latest attempt and unsuccessful attempt
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">

  <!-- Identity transform template -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Match opening comments and create elements -->
  <xsl:template match="comment()" priority="10">
    <xsl:variable name="commentContent" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    <xsl:message>Processing comment: <xsl:value-of select="$commentContent"/></xsl:message>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="starts-with($commentContent, '/')">
        <xsl:message>   Ignoring closing comment: <xsl:value-of select="$commentContent"/></xsl:message>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:message>Creating element for comment: <xsl:value-of select="$commentContent"/></xsl:message>
        <xsl:element name="{replace($commentContent, ' ', '')}">
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1][not(self::comment())]"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>


Can we assume that any comment is such a marker? Can those comment markers be nested or at a certain sibling level it is all flat, i.e. there is always one opening comment followed by it closing pair?

A first prototype to approach this with for-each-group group-starting-with/group-ending-with is
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="no" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[comment()]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-starting-with="comment()[not(matches(., '\s*/[a-z]+', 'i'))]">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="self::comment()">
            <xsl:variable name="comment-name" select="replace(., '^\s+|\s+$', '')"/>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="tail(current-group())" group-ending-with="comment()[matches(., '/' || $comment-name)]">
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current-group()[last()][self::comment()]">
                  <xsl:element name="{replace($comment-name, '\s+', '')}">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[not(position() = last())]"/>
                  </xsl:element>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>

Online fiddle with Saxon HE Java in the browser.

Thankyou Martin, I was a little concerned with your question/comment regarding assumption but I tried the code in hope.
At first it didn't create the output I needed but then I changed the  method="html" to "xml" and it worked a treat.  On further inspection of the input xml the comment are sometimes nested and some don't have a closing comment, but the code works really well for me.

The solution here uses a function that performs grouping with the xsl:iterate instruction, it has just one parameter, $stack that comprises a sequence of XPath maps.
The xsl:iterate instruction iterates each sequence of nodes, its parameter builds groups as a stack of XPath maps, at a 'start element event' a map entry is added to the stack and at the  'end element event' the last map entry is removed from the stack but copied as a child map-entry into what is now the last map entry. An apply-templates instruction ensures child elements are also processed recursively, here's the function that invokes xsl:iterate:
<xsl:function name="ccl:groupByCommentMarkers" as="map(*)">
  <xsl:param name="payload" as="node()*"/>
  <xsl:iterate select="$payload">      
    <xsl:param name="stack" as="map(*)+" select="map { 'element': 'root', 'nodes': ()}"/>
    <xsl:on-completion>
      <xsl:sequence select="$stack"/>
    </xsl:on-completion>
    <xsl:variable name="parentItem" as="map(*)" select="$stack[last()]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="parentAncestors" as="map(*)*" select="subsequence($stack, 1, count($stack) - 1)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="gParentItem" as="map(*)?" select="$stack[last() - 1]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="gParentAncestors" as="map(*)*" select="subsequence($stack, 1, count($stack) - 2)"/>
    
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="self::comment()[contains(., '/')]">
        <xsl:next-iteration>
          <xsl:with-param name="stack" 
            select="$gParentAncestors, map:put($gParentItem, 'nodes', ($gParentItem?nodes, $parentItem))"/>
        </xsl:next-iteration>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="self::comment()">
        <xsl:next-iteration>
          <xsl:with-param name="stack" select="($stack, map { 'element': normalize-space(), 'nodes': ()})"/>
        </xsl:next-iteration>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:variable name="groupedSelfAndDescendants" as="node()*">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="reconstructedGroups" as="node()*">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$groupedSelfAndDescendants" mode="reconstruct"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:next-iteration>
          <xsl:with-param name="stack" 
            select="$parentAncestors, map:put($parentItem, 'nodes', ($parentItem?nodes, $reconstructedGroups))"/>
        </xsl:next-iteration>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:iterate>
</xsl:function>

The XSLT template for invoking the function is in the default mode, there's another simple XSLT template in the reconstruct mode for converting the map structure into an element structure. We also need to use on-no-match="shallow-copy" for both modes:
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
<xsl:mode name="reconstruct" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
  <xsl:variable name="groupedCommentContents" as="map(*)" select="ccl:groupByCommentMarkers(node())"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$groupedCommentContents?nodes" mode="reconstruct"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match=".[. instance of map(*)]" mode="reconstruct">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="?element">
      <xsl:element name="{?element}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="?nodes" mode="#current"/>
      </xsl:element>       
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="?nodes" mode="#current"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>    
</xsl:template>

This XSLT should handle all cases of nesting or mixed-content, here's the output for the input XML supplied in the question (note TOP THUMBNAILS was renamed to be a valid XML name):
<html xmlns:ccl="com.deltaxml.ccl">
   <body>
      <IMAGECOUNT>
         <table width="100%">
            <tr>
               <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
                  <strong>
                     2 Images
                  </strong>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </IMAGECOUNT>
      <p>
         <strong>
            <SECTION>
               The section 
            </SECTION>
            <COUNTRY>
               The country
            </COUNTRY>
         </strong>
      </p>
      <DATE>
         <p>
            <font size="-1">
               <b>Date Posted: 09-Dec-2019</b>
            </font>
         </p>
      </DATE>
      <TEXT>
         <center>
            <p>
               <font size="-1">
                  Just some text
               </font>
            </p>
         </center>
      </TEXT>
      <TOP_THUMBNAILS>
         <table class="tabletopbottom" width="100%">
            <tr>
               <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
                  <img src="images/s1353556.jpg" alt="Cat"/>
                  <img src="images/s1164352.jpg" alt="Dog"/>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </TOP_THUMBNAILS>
   </body>
</html>

Some final comments:

xsl:for-each-group works best for regular data structures
you could create the XML element structure directly instead of using the interim XPath map, I just prefer not to
if required, you can add 'wellformedness-error' detection to the xsl:iterate instruction

